# Giving VNC access to screen shared via Xvnc

Tags: vnc

Let's say I want to share a screen with someone. I want this person to be able to control one application in this screen (the application is started with my user).

To do that I am doing the following:
- Starting a new X server with Xvnc in DISPLAY :2
- Running the application in this display
- Giving remote access using VNC

Doing so, will the person be able to open other programs or have access to my user? Is this a good solution? If not, what is a better/safer way to achieve what I want?

Comment: That depends on what the application does.

Comment: Make sense, if the application has an 'Open' option, the person will be able to view my files. But other than that, assuming that there is no application running, just an empty X with a black screen. Could the person switch X sessions or start a terminal using some keyboard shortcut?